# How I - Load a new Scene by clicking a Button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I try to figure out how to load a new scene by clicking a Button. So i come to this logic, but it seems this is wrong. Can someone help me with this? I really don´t get it..

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button NextLevel;

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        NextLevel.onClick = SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add a click listener to your button: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

Also, your LoadNextLevel() function is never called where the onClick could happen, so it is kind of a hen and egg problem here.

Comment: thanks i tried but it actually doesnt work. When i add a click listener like this: `NextLevel.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick) = SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1); ` it says TaskOnClick is not in the context

Comment: please edit your question that the code formatting is visible. But I guess you are missing the callback, so do it with (() => ...) as in the example for the third button.